# Is it a good practice to always do double relationships between documents in relational MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions, relationship, crud

I'm building a system where I have a couple of tables / collections, and these tables interact between themselves with 'One/Many' to 'One/Many' relationships.

The fact is that, in my current approach, I'm keeping double references between documents. For example:

**Users** pertain to 0..* **Companies**;

**Companies** have 0..* **Users**;

[image: Companies entry]

[image: Users entry]

As far as you can see, when a relationship is established, it is referred in both documents - the **User.companies** array is updated, and also the **Company.users** array is updated.

Therefore, we keep both collections updated with the relationships. It seems that, this way, reading (GET) operations will be optimized, because no join query will be needed; on the other hand, writing operations will be slower, because more than one document may be requested to be updated at each request.

For this, I created a standardized CRUD API to perform the main document and all its references updating;  I'm using mongoose transactions, so I can ensure that the operation is either completely done, or completely aborted, thus no integrity errors are expected.

Final question - is it a good practice? Or, despite its advantages and disadvantages, is it applicable / reasonable / scalable?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the answer can be 'it depends', as you might have experienced, you can use double relationships if it works for your requirement. It's good that you recognize that your solution is heavier on writing than reading documents because one of the things to consider in designing a MongoDB schema is: do you expect your application to be read intensive or write intensive? This is to save costs and of course make sure that your database operations are optimized as much as possible.

Based from experience, if possible I would not prefer to use double relationships. There are still room for errors (you'd be surprised), even if we try to cover these using transactions, tests, etc.

Lastly, it is not the best practice. For example, for **Company.users**, this is not a scalable solution as we do not know how many users there can be. Have a read at this article about MongoDB schema design best practices, rule 4 is applicable for this. Documents have a limit to their size and bigger documents mean slower and costlier operations.

https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/mongodb-schema-design-best-practices/

> Rule 4: Arrays should not grow without bound. If there are more than a couple of hundred documents on the many side, don't embed them; if there are more than a few thousand documents on the many side, don't use an array of ObjectID references. High-cardinality arrays are a compelling reason not to embed.

It's a really good and consice article, I recommend you to read it for more clarity on designing schemas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! More than a straightforward answer, I wanted exactly what you provided - arguments, and discussion!